# Save checkbox state with sharedpreferences

Tags: android, listview

In my code I added sharedpreferences and all but it doesnt save anything. What I need is that when a user ticks a few checkboxes the checkboxes should still be the same when the app is restarted or when the back button is pressed.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyActivity3 extends Activity {
private TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my3);
    Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcat);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeface);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("ticks", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.getString("name","");

    //LISTVIEW IS BELOW! Still needs check checkbox onItemClick and save state on exit and back pressed!
    String listArray[] = new String[] { "All", "Friends & Family", "Sports", "Outside",
            "At School", "Fitness", "Photography", "Food", "Beach", "Money" };
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= listArray.length - 1; i++) {
       HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("title", listArray[i]);
        aList.add(hm);
    }
    String[] sfrm = { "title"};
    int[] sto = { R.id.title};
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,
            R.layout.row_layout, sfrm, sto);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                               int position, long id) {
           switch (position) {
           }
       }
   });
}

public void save(View view)
{
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("ticks", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("key","");
    editor.commit();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation8, R.anim.animation7);
    }
}
```

here's my .xml where the checkbox has an onClick="save" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<com.MR.brd.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Country name"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="48sp" />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/chk"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_design"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="save"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I followed a tutorial on the sharedpreferences but clearly I am not getting it somehow...

Comment: OK according to your code when you press a Checkbox its saves the state but what happens when you press 2 checksboxes is it overrides the old one? when do you call the save function and why you saving with key but reading with name?

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought that if I put the onClick in the .xml file it would be fine because it counts for each checkbox in the listview. The name i must indeed change. I call the save function when a box is pressed

Comment: if you have more the one Checkbox you need to create a unique key to each one .. plus String result = sharedPreferences.getString("name",""); you forget to return the result

Comment: Can you help me by sharing the code you mean? Im still new to android programming :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving nothing on shared preference:

```
editor.putString("key","");
```

always save a empty string. And on onCreate you are not using a retrieved string and you must use the same key.

```
sharedPreferences.getString("name","");
```

You must change "**name**" for "**key**".

Also you are not catching the event when checked state change on CheckBox. In some part of your code, you must set an OnCheckedChangeListener for checkboxes, because setOnItemClickListener is fired when one view of ListView is selected, not when a checkBox is selected or deselected.

Modify your onCreate Activity method, and remove **save** method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my3);
    Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcat);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeface);

    String[] listArray = new String[] { "All", "Friends & Family", "Sports", "Outside", "At School", "Fitness", "Photography", "Food", "Beach", "Money" };
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("status", MODE_PRIVATE);

    Boolean[] checkedStatus = new Boolean[listArray.length];
    for ( int index = 0; index < checkedStatus.length; index++)
        checkedStatus[index] = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Integer.toString(index), false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, listArray, checkedStatus);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And create MyAdapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

String[] values;
Boolean[] checkedStatus;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] values, Boolean[] checkedStatus) {
    super(context, resource, values);

    this.values = values;
    this.checkedStatus = checkedStatus;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return values.length;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return values[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    CheckBox box = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk);
    box.setTag(position);
    box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    box.setChecked(checkedStatus[position]);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Integer index = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
    checkedStatus[index] = isChecked;
    String key = index.toString();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getContext().getSharedPreferences("status", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key,isChecked);
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

Also, modify a checkbox declaration on .xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Country name"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="48sp" />

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/chk"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_design"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

removing,

```
android:onClick="save"
```

Comment: So just change it to key and it should be fine? Or do I need to put something inbetween the empty "" tags?

Comment: Could you edit my code to make it work? All these terms and stuff, it's too much for a newbie :P * Thanks :)

Comment: No, I will post the changes on my answer.

Comment: Okay, I will await the changes :)

Comment: Do I create a new java class file and post the MyAdapter in there or do I just copy it in my activity?

Comment: Create a new file for MyAdapter class.

Comment: Working like a mothaf*n charm! You're the man! The checkboxes stay saved. Perfect. But one thing, the text in the listview is Country Name?

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understand you want to say me with "Country Name"

Comment: In the .xml file it says android:text="Country name" . So now instead of Friends &Family and all the other things, it displays Country Name 10 times

Comment: Ahh, ok, this is for CustomTextView .xml design, do you want display only a text on left side of view and checkbox on right?

Comment: Yes exactly, on the left for example "All" and a checkbox on the right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59542/discussion-between-cristianowilson-and-joseph).

Comment: I update a code, change a CustomView on xml for a TextView, and on adapter, see a lines to set a text to TextView. Remember that a font color for TextView is white, if you don´t see a text.

Comment: These two lines need to be added, no? : Integer index = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
    checkedStatus[index] = isChecked; **** WORKS PERFECTLY Thanks!

Comment: Check the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59542/discussion-between-cristianowilson-and-joseph

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to save a lot of code ( and possible bugs ) you can use AXT - then it looks like this:

```
AXT.at(yourCheckBox).careForCheckedStatePersistence("some_tag");
```

the tag in your case needs the position of your checkbox.

https://github.com/ligi/AXT